# Mudar URL de /controller?id=1 para /controller/1

Tags: c#, mvc, asp.net-core

Na minha view tenho dois botões que passam parâmetros via GET para o index do meu controller, o problema é que a URL não fica com o tradicional ?id=1  e eu queria fazer com que ficasse assim:  /controller/1

**View:**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(FormMethod.Get))
        {
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="1" name="id">sites1</button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="2" name="id">sites2</button><br />

        }
```

**Controller:**

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> Index(int? id)
    {
        var listaDeSites = await _listaService.ListaDeSitesAsync(id);
        return View(listaDeSites);
    }
```

Comment: Poderia postar o código da sua classe RouteConfig? Obrigado.

Comment: Ta no padrão do asp.net core app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
               
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });

Comment: ps.: Você quer dizer `/Controller/1`, `/Controller/Action/1` ou `./Action/1` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você poderia colocar o seguinte annotation:

```
[HttpGet("{id}")]
```

ficando assim:

```
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(int? id)
{
    var listaDeSites = await _listaService.ListaDeSitesAsync(id);
    return View(listaDeSites);
}
```